# Input not terminating in scanf in C++

Tags: c++, input, scanf

The input is not terminating for the input

```
5  
1 10  
10 8  
8 2  
2 1  
1 10
```

but for other input like

```
5   
1 1  
1 2   
1 3   
1 4   
1 5
```

it is working fine.
I have tried various ways like by using if condition to terminate the loop but it is not working.

```
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<cstdio>
// where a==breadth b== index
#define MP(a,b)  make_pair(-a,b)
#define INDEX it->second
#define K1 a[INDEX][2]
#define getL(i,k)  a[(i)][0]
#define getB(i,k)  a[(i)+(k)-1][1]
#define COST(a,b,c)   ((a)*(b)*(c))
#define REMOVE(a,i) s.erase(s.find(MP(a,i)))
#define PUSH(a,i) s.insert(MP(a,i))
#define FIND(a,i) s.find(MP(a,i))
using namespace std;

set  < pair <  int , int > > s;
set < pair <  int , int > >::iterator it,p;


#define MAX 1000
int a[MAX][3];

int solve(int n){
    int i,idx,idx2,k1,k2,last=n-2;
    int value=0;
    a[n-1][2]=1;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        a[i][2]=1;
        s.insert(MP(a[i][1],i));//the value will be added on the basis of hte
    }
    cout << s.size();
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        cout << "the minum";
        it=s.begin();
        idx=INDEX;
        k1=K1;
        idx2=idx+k1;
        k2=a[idx2][2];//matrix with which the idx matrix has to be multiplied

        s.erase(it);
        cout << getB(idx2 ,k1);
        cout << idx2;
        value+=COST(getL(idx,k1),getB(idx,k1),getB(idx2,k2));
        a[idx][2]=k1+k2;// all the values will be update by now
        a[idx2][2]=k1+k2;
        if(idx==last)// if the index has to be equal to the last
        {// multiply the matrix but don't put it in the tree
            last=idx-a[(idx-1)][2];//
        }
        else
        {
            REMOVE(getB(idx2,k2),idx2);
            PUSH(getB(idx2,k2),idx);
        }
    }

    return value;
}


int main(){
    int n,i;
    printf("Enter the number of matrix\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Now Enter the dimensions of the matrix\n");
    //  the output is not terminating in the loop
    //
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&a[i][0],&a[i][1]);
    }
    cout << "Input terminated";

    printf("\nThe approx number of calculations required are %d",solve(n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add some temporary print-outs for debugging? Print the value of `n` before you go through the loop, the value of `i` each time through, the return value of `scanf`, etc.

Comment: Please learn to indent systematically.  It improves the chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: *Always* check return value of any `scanf` function. It returns how many items it parsed, and if it is less than what you supplied as arguments, it means "parse error", and *will leave the unparsed data in the stream* so next `scanf` will again see it and fail again.

Comment: @JasonC I tried adding some temporarry print-outs but it not working it is still unable to parse the last input

Comment: @hyde It is working of for some input, it is giving the TLE on ideone

Comment: I just want to know why it is not terminating for the input given above

Comment: "I tried adding some temporarry print-outs but it not working" ? What does *that* mean? What was the output? What are the results of checking the return value of `scanf()`? And if `solve()` and the rest of the cruft in this has nothing to do with your input parsing problem, get rid of it and clip this down to a [**Short**, self-contained, compilable example](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: @WhozCraig I used printf("%d %d %d ",a[i][0],a[i][1],i); after the scanf to check wether scanf is taking input ?? and printf is printing value upto i equal to 3, it is not going to value 4 and and is not terminating , I don't know may be the rest of the code is interfering with it so put the whole code.

Comment: And the return value of `scanf()` for each iteration is? Minus the cruft, [this works](https://ideone.com/W2F9hI).

Comment: @WhozCraig scanf is returning 2 but it is not exiting from the loop  .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using endl with cout can cause problems a lot of times. I don't know the exact reason but I have faced this before especially when you use print statements with cout before using printf or scanf.